# Hadoop to Teradata - I have to run a script in Teradata using sqoop or some Hadoop tool

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have a Teradata script which basically creates a volatile table and update the records in columns by grabbing the data from different tables in Teradata.

The challenge I'm facing here is I have to run the whole script from Hadoop and select the columns from the volatile table that is created and import it into Hive.

Volatile table will be deleted when the session closes to the user I'm logging in. I have to create the table once a day and import the table that is created.

Comment: Don't use a volatile table?

Comment: is there any way to create volatile table and pull the records out of it ?

Comment: I don't think you can possibly sqoop from a volatile table, it only exists inside the Teradata session, which sqoop has nothing to do with.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, After I dig deep into that I found out its not possible to import from volatile table. if I can create a physical table and overwrite it every time I can import the data. But can you please help me how can I run the whole sql file on Teradata and pull the data from the physical table ? I know sqoop can import the table but will it work to run the whole sql file and get the data ?

Comment: @Rob: sounds like you may need to load data into a physical table in Teradata marked with a runId column that is common both to the Teradata script and to the sqoop import.  Perhaps load the data into a volatile table and insert select them into the physical table with the runId set to a known value for all of the rows.  Then use Sqoop to pull the rows belonging to the runId.  The cleanup of old data could be done on the next job or at the end of this job.

Comment: @Rob:  You may want to look at the Hadoop table operators that are available in Teradata.  These can push data from Teradata into Hadoop and vice versa.  They run fast because they use parallel loading between the Teradata and Hadoop nodes.